# Do Rust closures really not need type annoations?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm currently reading the Rust book, and I have just reached the topic [`closures`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html).
A detail that has surprised me, is that the Rust book sais that

> Closures don’t require you to annotate the types of the parameters

I immeadiatly tested that, since it appeared really counter-intuitive to how Rust usually works. Thus, i copied [exactly the closure they used](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#refactoring-with-closures-to-store-code), pasted it into my code, and... got an error:

```rust
fn some_closure() {
    let expensive_closure = |num| {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        num
    };
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:14:30
   |
14 |     let expensive_closure = |num| {
   |                              ^^^ consider giving this closure parameter a type

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I sure know the meaning of that error, still I am confused by it, since not only the book, but also the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/closure-expr.html#attributes-on-closure-parameters) specify that theres no annotations needed, yet I am getting this error.

Is this just a recent change that hasn't been documented yet, or is there something I misunderstand?

Comment: `num` is used in absolutely no way. So there's absolutely no way to determine its type. Did you want to use `num` instead of `2` in the closure ? Is that a typo ?

Comment: In addition to what the answer says, there are also cases where the compiler _could_ figure out the types, but doesn't (yet). You shouldn't take "don't require you to annotate" as 100% guarantee, it's more of a best-effort attempt to intuit the types. (But this differs from functions where no such attempt exist, intentionally.) Also, you can count on future versions of the compiler to only require annotations in _fewer_ cases, as failing to compile existing code would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler needs to be able to deduce the type of the argument in some way, this can happen through explicit type annotations as in `num: i32` or through contextual information such as

```
fn use_some_closure() {
    let expensive_closure = |num| {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        num
    };
    expensive_closure(42);
}
```

Without annotation or usage there's no way to figure out what `num` is.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=094eb83160a423cc35705dc8b0b09992)

Answer (score 5):

> the book, but also the reference specify that theres no annotations needed, yet I am getting this error.

No, the key word of the book and the reference is *required*, which is different from *needed*. Something can ben contextually needed even when it's not generally required.

For closure the distinction is in opposition to "static functions" (`fn`) for which annotations are a *syntactic requirement*: you can not write valid static functions without providing type annotations, whereas generally speaking you can write closures without type annotations.

However the compiler still needs to know the concrete type of the closure, which requires being able to infer the parameter & return types. If it can not because there are not enough constraints, it will complain and need explicitly specified types.

In your example, there is nothing constraining the type of `num`, so rustc has no way to know what the *concrete* type of `num` is, and therefore is not able to infer what the concrete type of the closure should be.

But in most cases there is e.g.

```
let it = repeat(5).map(|x| x+1);
```

the compiler is happy with that, because the input and output types of the closure are necessarily what `map` provides, which is `Repeat::Item`, which in this case is `i32` (because that's what integer literals default to barring other constraints).